# Sporadically logged out of Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Just wondering if anybody has come across anything similar to this at all? Would appreciate any light that could be shed, or any suggestions as to the next steps of what to try.

Problem

A client of mine has a drupal 7 website, with both their intranet and main website on the same installation. When they log into the back end, they are sporadically logged out.

We cannot replicate this issue on our computers, logging into the same back end, with user accounts with the same permissions and privilege setup.

The only way we managed to replicate the issue is by using the same remote desktop system that the client uses on all machines within the company (and their staff use when working from home, off-site, etc)

It’s a windows remote desktop environment, with Internet Explorer the only allowed browser.

This is the only time the logging out occurs. There isn’t a known trigger, sometimes they get logged out after 4 or 5 clicks around the back end, sometimes they can be logged in for 10-15 minutes, making changes to content, and upon pressing save (or any link on the page) you are redirected to the login page, because you don’t have the permissions to carry out what you just tried to do (save the page, for example).

Things we’ve tried

Turning on/off modules systematically.
Updated drupal core.
Changing settings within internet explorer with regards to sessions and cookies.
Clearing the user sessions table from the database, incase something in there was corrupt.

Comment: Maybe they "jump" from www to non-www domain?

Comment: Check cookie setting into settings.php , yo need to specify domain like
`$conf['cdn_url'] = 'http://mysite.fr';`
  `$cookie_domain = '.mysite.fr';`